# Compiling Error- Unreachable Statement

Tags: java

I'm getting an unreachable statement error in demo code from my book on this line

```
  System.out.print("Contents of bigQ: ");
```

Here is the rest of the code.

```
 class demonstration {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        qdsd bigQ = new qdsd(100);
        qdsd smallQ = new qdsd(4);
        char ch;
        int i;

        System.out.println("Using bigQ to store the alphabet.");
        // put some numbers into bigQ
        for(i = 0; 9 <26;i++)
            bigQ.put((char) ('A' + i));

        // retrieve and display elements form bigQ

        System.out.print("Contents of bigQ: ");

        for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            ch = bigQ.get();
            if(ch != (char) 0) System.out.print(ch);

        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.print("Using smallQ to print out some errors.");
        // Now, use smallQ to generatate some errors
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println("Attempting to store "  +
                    (char) ('Z' - i));
            System.out.println();

        }
        System.out.println();
    // more errors on smallQ
    System.out.print("Contents of smallQ: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        ch = smallQ.get();

        if(ch != (char) 0) System.out.print(ch);

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you think the condition `9 <26` will ever end?

Comment: 9<26 is always true.hence infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there's an infinite loop just before it:

```
for(i = 0; 9 <26;i++)
    bigQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
```

Since `9 < 26` will *always* be true, the loop will execute forever.  Did you mean to do this instead?:

```
for(i = 0; i <26;i++)
    bigQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
```

Comment: It won't let me accept your answer for eight more minutes

Answer (score 1):

For loop condition (`9 <26`) makes it an infinite loop.

- Change that expression
- Use break in for loop